# How to search files by directory and file name combo pattern

Tags: command-line, find

I want to find all .xml files in all directories and subdirectories with name 'metadata' in the filesystem.  Is there a way to search by pattern similar to

```
find . -name  */metadata/*.xml" (mixing find command and Gradle paralance)
```

?

Comment: `find / -type f -name '*metadata*.xml' ` but, i am sure that has a dozen of duplicate questions and answers. Search it.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou wouldn't that need to be `-path` rather than `-name`? e.g. `find / -type f -name '*/metadata/*.xml'`. Also it's not clear whether the OP wants `metadata` anywhere in the path, or just as the immediate parent (in the latter case, `find / -type f -regex '.*/metadata/[^/]*\.xml'` might do it, at least in GNU find)

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, it might require -path , is not very clear if metadata is  part of the filename (so can go at -name) or can also be part of the path , and thus `-path` should be used (BTW you have a typo error in your comment, right? you suggest to use -path but you wrote -name) .

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou doh! yes I meant `-path`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ find / -path "*/metadata/*" -name "*.xml"
```

or, shorter (since `*` matches past the slashes in pathnames when used with `-path`),

```
$ find / -path "*/metadata/*.xml"
```

Note: I'm using `/` as you said "in the filesystem", which I interpreted to mean "anywhere".

Alternatively, using `locate` (will only find files accessible to all users):

```
$ locate "/metadata/" | grep '\.xml$'
```

(This will work somewhat like the first `find` above)

Comment: Works perfectly!

Comment: I think this info is useful.  I could not find anything close when I searched.  Not sure why someone down voted the question :(

Answer (score 0):

What you need to realize is that the -name in 'find' is really the 'basename'
Hence to get at the actual filename we can run a nested find wherein we first locate a directory whose name is 'metadata' and then look for any *.xml files under the said directory:

```
find . -type d -name metadata -exec sh -c '
shift $1;
while case $# in 0 ) break;; esac; do
   find "${1}/." ! -name . -prune -type f -name \*.xml
   shift
done
' 2 1 {} +
```

Answer (score -1):

This is sort of sloppy, but while you are in the parent directory of your choosing you could try

```
grep -nr "*metadata/*xml" .
```

Comment: I want to search in subdirectories as well.  Updated the question to make it clearer